# The largest number of answers

Tags: support, answers, statistics

I would like to know how to find the posts that contain the largest number of  answers.

Comment: You can search for questions that have at least a given number of answers by searching for `answers:50`: http://mathoverflow.net/search?q=answers%3A50 I don't know if you can sort the results by the number of answers. The highest number of answers is 187: http://mathoverflow.net/q/23478/55893

Answer (score 9):

This is a perfect task for the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com), which allows you to make SQL queries to the database of any network site. Here is a query that gives the top 50 questions sorted by answer count.

http://data.stackexchange.com/mathoverflow/query/264370/questions-with-most-answers